# link to page position without id attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several divs without id attribute:

```
<div name="divPub">Content A</div>
<div name="divPub">Content B</div>
<div name="divPub">Content C</div>
```

I have created an array of divs:

```
var $element_to_scroll_to = document.getElementsByName("divPub");
```

What I need is to jump to a specific div based on it array position:

```
var scrollTop = $element_to_scroll_to[index].offset().top;
window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
```

but throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $element_to_scroll_to[index].offset is not a function.
```

I also tried:

```
location.hash = $element_to_scroll_to[index];
```

but does not works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you mix DOM and jQuery, you are causing yourself bugs. `element_to_scroll_to` is an html collection and you treat it like it has jQuery methods. There is no offset() method in DOM.

Comment: You're mixing your jquery and javascript objects.  `document.getElementsByName` isn't a jquery object so doesn't have `.offset()` method.  Either use `$($element_to_scroll_to[index]).offset().top;` or `$element_to_scroll_to[index].offsetTop;`

Comment: @freedomn-m ok but either way offsetTop always returns 0

Comment: But at least you're not getting the `TypeError` error anymore... :)

Answer (score 0):

`offsetTop` is a property not a method, try this:

```
var scrollTop = $element_to_scroll_to[index].offsetTop;
```

`.offset` is a method available on jQuery element not on regular DOM elements. Read more about [jQuery offset here.](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)